# Importing view in jest for unit testing gives invariant violation error

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs

We were trying to migrate our unit tests to Jest (from Mocha Chai Expect) for an existing application, when our team ran into this issue where as soon as we try to import a View (say DummyView.js), we get an

> Invariant Violation error: You must pass a component to the function
>   returned by connect. Instead received undefined.

We get this error even if we have commented out all test code. It fails on the import itself.

This DummyView.js is itself used inside a container in our code.

```
// DummyContainer.js
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import DummyView from './DummyView.js'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => { 
  tabType: state.tabType,
  miscProps: state.miscProps
}
const mapDispatchProps = (dispatch) => {...}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DummyView)

// DummyView.js
import React from 'react'
import Tab1Section from './Tab1Section'
import Tab2Section from './Tab2Section'
import Tab3Section from './Tab3Section'

const DummyView = ({tabType, miscProps}) => {
  const TabRender = null
  switch(tabType) {
    case 1:
      TabRender = <Tab1Section { ...miscProps } />
    case 2:
      TabRender = <Tab1Section { ...miscProps } />
    case 3:
      TabRender = <Tab1Section { ...miscProps } />
    default:
      TabRender = (
        <div><span>Error</span><div>
      )
  }

  return (TabRender)
}

export default DummyView
```

Does Jest not allow to test the DummyView alone? Why/ how does it know its used inside a container?

Does it make sense to test only a container then? Assuming the View will be tested along with it?

PS: I'm aware invariant violation means the HTML is probably formatted incorrectly. But how do I get to the tests if it fails on import?

Comment: maybe the DummyView does not use module export (`export default ...`)? Try `import * as DummyView from './DummyView.js'`. Or you may export it named `export DummyView`. In any case, this looks like an import problem (i bed DummyView is undefined in you code snippet)

Comment: @lipp - I've updated to show how my component, container look.

Answer (score 1):

This usually is an import/export problem. Your syntax assumes `DummyView` to be the default export.

In order to have you snippet working, the DummyView.js` file should look like this.

```
export default class DummyView extends React.Component {}
```

The following will NOT WORK

```
export class DummyView extends React.Component {}
```

And this will also NOT WORK

```
class DummyView extends React.Component {}
module.exports = DummyView
```

Comment: I see your point regarding the import/ export syntax. What if the DummyView is not a class based component? Its actually something like this - `const DummyView = ({ ...props}) => { return <  ... some view /> }; export default DummyView;`

Comment: Exporting functional components is just the same. This should work... could you post your DummyView.js file?

Comment: Its actually project code so I cannot post that. I'll try replicating the issue with a little POC and update it in my question.

Comment: I just see the const DummyView = ... Do you `export default DummyView` ?